# Convert numpy array to hex bytearray

Tags: python, numpy, hex, arrays

I want to convert a numpy array to a bytestring in python 2.7. Lets say my numpy array `a` is a simple `2x2` array, looking like this:

```
[[1,10],
 [16,255]]
```

My question is, how to convert this array to a string of bytes or bytearray with the output looking like:

```
\x01\x0A\x10\xff
```

or equally well:

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x0A\x10\xff')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `a` is an array of `np.int8` type, you can use [`tobytes()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) to get the output you specify:

```
>>> a.tobytes()
b'\x01\n\x10\xff'
```

Note that my terminal prints `\x0A` as the newline character `\n`.

Calling the Python built in function `bytes` on the array `a` does the same thing, although `tobytes()` allows you to specify the memory layout (as per the documentation).

If `a` has a type which uses more bytes for each number, your byte string might be padded with a lot of unwanted null bytes. You can either cast to the smaller type, or use slicing (or similar). For example if `a` is of type `int64`:

```
>>> a.tobytes()[::8]
b'\x01\n\x10\xff
```

As a side point, you can also interpret the underlying memory of the NumPy array as bytes using `view`. For instance, if `a` is still of `int64` type:

```
>>> a.view('S8')
array([[b'\x01', b'\n'],
       [b'\x10', b'\xff']], dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: Just for someone seeing that in the future: 'tobyte()' could also be 'tostring()' in some numpy releases, moreover 'bytes(a)' doesn't work for me.