# Is it possible to effectively initialize bytearray with non-zero value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-bytearray

I need to have huge boolean array. All values should be initialized as "True":

```
arr = [True] * (10 ** 9)
```

But created as above it takes too much memory. So I decided to use `bytearray` for that:

```
arr = bytearray(10 ** 9)  # initialized with zeroes
```

Is it possible to initialize `bytearray` with `b'\x01'` as effectively as it is initialized by `b'\x00'`?

I understand I could initialize `bytearray` with zeros and inverse my logic. But I'd prefer not to do that if possible.

**timeit**:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def f1():
...   return bytearray(10**9)
... 
>>> def f2():
...   return bytearray(b'\x01'*(10**9))
... 
>>> timeit(f1, number=100)
14.117428014000325
>>> timeit(f2, number=100)
51.42543800899875
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy, use sequence multiplication:

```
arr = bytearray(b'\x01') * 10 ** 9
```

Same approach works for initializing with zeroes (`bytearray(b'\x00') * 10 ** 9`), and it's generally preferred, since passing integers to the `bytes` constructor has been a source of confusion before (people sometimes think they can make a single element `bytes` with the value of the integer).

You want to initialize the single element `bytearray` first, then multiply, rather than multiplying the `bytes` and passing it to the `bytearray` constructor, so you avoid doubling your peak memory requirements (and requiring reading from one huge array and writing to another, on top of the simple `memset`-like operation on a single array that any solution requires).

In my local tests, `bytearray(b'\x01') * 10 ** 9` runs exactly as fast as `bytearray(10 ** 9)`; both took ~164 ms per loop, vs. 434 ms for multiplying the `bytes` object, then passing it to `bytearray` constructor.

Comment: This is an outstanding explanation and should be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html) for this sort of thing.  On my computer, `np.ones` (which initializes an array of all-1 values) with boolean "dtype" is just as fast as the bare `bytearray` constructor:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def f1(): return bytearray(10**9)
>>> def f2(): return np.ones(10**9, dtype=np.bool)
>>> timeit(f1, number=100)
24.9679438900057
>>> timeit(f2, number=100)
24.732190757000353
```

If you don't want to use third-party modules, another option with competitive performance is to create a one-element `bytearray` and then expand that, instead of creating a large byte-string and converting it to a bytearray.

```
>>> def f3(): return bytearray(b'\x01')*(10**9)
>>> timeit(f3, number=100)
24.842667759003234
```

Since my computer appears to be slower than yours, here is the performance of your original option for comparison:

```
>>> def fX(): return bytearray(b'\x01'*(10**9))
>>> timeit(fX, number=100)
56.61828187300125
```

Cost in all cases is going to be dominated by allocating a decimal gigabyte of RAM and writing to every byte of it.  `fX` is roughly twice as slow as the other three functions because it has to do this twice.  A good rule of thumb for you to remember when working with code like this is: *minimize the number of allocations*.  It may be worth dropping down to a lower-level language in which you can explicitly control allocation (if you don't know any such language already, I recommend [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/)).

Comment: Other than `%timeit`, this is a duplicate of my earlier answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `numpy`?  You could do:

```
import numpy as np
np.ones(10,dtype=bool)
```

Returns:

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Also, you can easily convert back to bytes with `ndarray.tobytes()` as in:

```
x = np.ones(10,dtype=bool)
x.tobytes()
# returns: b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136377/2573061) for more details.